# How to specify formula in linear model with 100 dependent variables without having to write them explicitly in R

Tags: r, regression

The problem is to (a) model the intra day demand in ATM Widthrawals and (b) create prediction intervals for future demand. One day has 144 10-minute periods and my dataset is the number of ATM widthrawals in each period. Here is a chart so you can have a glipse of what I'm talking about.
[image: One day sample]

My dataset also has other data (mainly dummies), such as Weekday and Holiday. For the purpose of this post, I be using the following data.frame as a representation of my dataset (which has only 6 time periods, between 00:10 and 01:00 and not the full day)

```
df <- data.frame(H0010=1, H0020=2, H0030=3, H0050=4, H0050=5, H0100=6,
                 WeekDay=7, Holiday=8)
```

The first idea that crossed my mind was to fit a linear regression. More precisely, a multivariate multiple linear regression. But because I have 144 dependent variables (one for each 10-minute period) and not only 6, my code in R would be hugely long:

```
lm.fit <- lm(cbind(H0010, H0020, H0030, H0050, H0050, H0100,
                   H0200, H0210, H0220, H0230, H0240, H0250,

                  (and in goes on and on till midnight)

                   H2310, H2320, H2330, H2340, H2350, H2359) 
                  ~ WeekDay + Holiday, data = df)
```

Is there a way I could write the model formula without having to specify all the 144 dependent variables?

I would also apreciate any other thoughts on how to address this problem using other methods (although this posts question is the above mencioned).

**EDIT**:
My dataset is composed by the dependent variables (number of transactions) and dummies which are factors. As so, the solution `lm(cbind(-Weekday, -Holiday) ~ Weekday + Holiday, data=df)` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f <- sprintf("cbind(%s) ~ WeekDay + Holiday", paste(names(df)[1:6], collapse = ", "))
lm(f, data = df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can select variables by specifying which you would like to exclude:

```
lm(cbind(-WeekDay, -Holiday) ~ WeekDay + Holiday, data=df)
```

**EDIT:**

How's this? I included a more realistic dataframe too.

```
df <- data.frame(H0010=rnorm(100, 1, 1), H0020=rnorm(100, 2, 1), 
             H0030=rnorm(100, 3, 1), H0050=rnorm(100, 4, 1), 
             H0050=rnorm(100, 5, 1), H0100=rnorm(100, 6, 1),
             WeekDay=factor(c(rep(seq(1,7), 14), 1, 2)),
             Holiday=factor(rbinom(100, 1, prob = .05)))


y <- as.matrix(df[,1:6])
x <- model.matrix(~df$WeekDay+df$Holiday)
lm(y~0+x) #suppress intercept, as it's in the model.matrix
```

Comment: As for the general approach, you should consider a timeseries model. Facebook recently released a package for this type of problem, though I don't think it handles hourly data. But you can see the general idea and maybe adapt it for your purposes:

https://facebookincubator.github.io/prophet/

Comment: I'm sorry, my post in not complete and as a result, your solution which seemed perfect doesn't work. My dummies factors and such, R returns `'-' not meaningfull for factors`. I will add this info to the post.

Comment: I will look carefully into prophet, thank you for your sugestion!